# White gap at the bottom of the page on scrolling upwards in mobile

Tags: html, css

I have my webpage working fine on desktops and other large screeens. But on mobile, there is a white gap showing up at the bottom of the page, when I touch and scroll upwards like this -

[image]

I tried changing the initial-scale, minimum scale and maximum scales values to 0.6, 07 and 1.0 by referring other answers in stackoverflow. Can any please help me out in fixing this. Here is my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/m7z0kqa5/

I am setting the page to viewport height using this code -

```
   $(".chat-history").height($(window).height() - $(".chat-message").height() - $(".header").height()-40);
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        $(".chat-history").height($(window).height() - $(".chat-message").height() - $(".header").height()-40);
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There can be several reasons. 1. Might be an issue of height on smaller screens 2. Might be due to an element getting padding on smaller screen.
etc

Comment: @AhmadHabib Thank you. Removing height:100vh on one of the divs fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Removing height:100vh on one of the divs fixed the issue